# Isset() equivalent in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, isset

I'm a newbie in Python and I'm struggling with an issue which is for sure easy for other people, but I just don't find a solution.
I want to insert something into a DB table if a row with the same timestamp does not exist yet:

```
sqlConnection = sqlite3.connect('/etc/grafana/db/database.db')
                    sqlCursor = sqlConnection.cursor()
                    print("Successfully Connected to SQLite")
                    
                    sqlInsert = sqlCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ezv WHERE timestamp = ?", (timestamp,))
                    sqlConnection.commit()
                    
                    if len(sqlCursor.fetchone()) >= 1:
                        print("Row already exists")
                    else:                       
                        sqlInsert = sqlCursor.execute("INSERT INTO ezv VALUES (?,?)", (timestamp, value))
                        sqlConnection.commit()
                        print("Record inserted successfully ", sqlCursor.rowcount)
                        print('insert')
      
                    sqlCursor.close()
```

So, if the row already exists, the message is printed successfully. But if not, an exception is thrown as "len(sqlCursor.fetchone()" is empty. From PHP I know isset() to handle cases like this, but I can't find a working equivalent for it in Python.

Can somebody help?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the actual, complete, verbatim error message with backtrace? Even in PHP, `isset` is something you should hardly ever be using if you structure your program well, so forget about that as an approach…

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ezv.py", line 27, in <module>
    if len(sqlCursor.fetchone()) >= 1:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: "fetchone would either return the row or None" --> Oh, I did not know that. Will do it like that, thank you so much!